# Pandas: How to count values of mixed character cases in different columns in Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe with different columns

| COUNTRY | COUNTRY1 | COUNTRY2 | hp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Italy | uk | france | 50 |
| uk | france | italy | 150 |

I would like to count the countries in different columns by row(**without using melt**) to get and output like this:

```
Italy 2

France 2

Uk 2
```

**I tried different options as `loc` and `groupby` but it doesn't work.**

Thank you

Comment: [`Melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) it and then `value_counts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the `COUNTRY*` columns by [`.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), then [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to a single column with the country names.

As your country names have mixed character letter cases, you can change country names to Title case (first letter capital letter) by [`str.title()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.title.html) before we count the occurences with [`.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), as follows:

```
df.filter(like='COUNTRY').stack().str.title().value_counts()
```

**Result:**

```
Italy     2
Uk        2
France    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

the suggestion of @Henry Yik is way more efficient, and in combination with a groupby can solve your problem.
also, try this:

```
def count_entries(df, col_name):
    
    country_count = {}
    
    # Extract column from DataFrame: col
    col = df[col_name]
    
    # Iterate over country column in DataFrame
    for entry in col:
        # If the country is in langs_count, add 1
        if entry in country_count.keys():
            country_count[entry] = country_count[entry] + 1 
        # Else add the language to langs_count, set the value to 1
        else:
            country_count[entry] = 1

    return country_count
print(df.columns)

# Call count_entries(): result
for col_name in df.columns:
    result = count_entries(df, col_name)
    print(result)
```